# Node.js sequelize to get only count of many to many associated object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My db structure is as follows:

I have `assessment`, `question`, `tag` table. The association between these table is as follows:

1. `assessment` and `question` are linked by third table `assessment_questions`
2. `question` and `tag` are linked by third table `question_tag` that is  many to many relationship.

My usecase is: I have `assessmentId` from which I fetch questions associated with it and also I want `tagCount` of each question fetched for given `assessmentId.`
To fetch questions and tags I'm using below sequelize api:

```
   assessment.findAll({
        where: {
            id: assessmentId,
            is_active: true
        },include:[{
            model: question,
            where : {
                is_active: true
            },
            required: false,
            through: {attributes: []},
            include: [{
                model:tag,
                through: {attributes: []}
            }]
        }]
      })
```

To get the `tagCount` for the questions I tried `sequelize.fn("count")` and  `sequelize.literal` but it's not fetching the `tagCount` of question.
Please help me how to use count function for many to many relationship.
Please update above sequelize query to get `tagCount`.